# How to find who is the most important individual in the network using networkx in python?

Tags: python, facebook, dataset, networkx, network-analysis

I am using facebook snap dataset and making a graph on it using **networkX** on python. But not been able to find the most important or you can say the most connected one in the network.

The code i am using i making a graph on facebook snap dataset is here:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


'''Exploratory Data Analysis'''
g = nx.read_edgelist('facebook_combined.txt', create_using=nx.Graph(), nodetype=int)
print nx.info(g)

'''Simple Graph'''
sp = nx.spring_layout(g)
nx.draw_networkx(g, pos=sp, with_labels=False, node_size=35)
# plt.axes("off")
plt.show()
```

The result it gives is this:

[image]

The link to the dataset is [here](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/facebook_combined.txt.gz)

The source of dataset is [here](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/egonets-Facebook.html)

**But the question is that how can i find the most important individual in this network ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to define "importance" is the individual's betweenness centrality. The betweenness centrality is a measure of how many shortest paths pass through a particular vertex. The more shortest paths that pass through the vertex, the more central the vertex is to the network.

Because the shortest path between any pair of vertices can be determined independently of any other pair of vertices.
To do this, we will use the Pool object from the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) library and the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) library.

First thing we need to do is partition the vertices of the network into n subsets where n is dependent on the number of processors we have access to. For example, if we use a machine with 32 cores, we partition the Facebook network in 32 chunks with each chunk containing 128 vertices.

Now instead of one processor computing the betweenness for all 4,039 vertices, we can have 32 processors computing the betweenness for each of their 128 vertices in parallel. This drastically reduces the run-time of the algorithm and allows it to scale to larger networks.

The code i used is this:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


'''Exploratory Data Analysis'''
    g = nx.read_edgelist('facebook_combined.txt', create_using=nx.Graph(), nodetype=int)
print nx.info(g)

'''Parallel Betweenness Centrality'''
from multiprocessing import Pool
import itertools

spring_pos = nx.spring_layout(g)


def partitions(nodes, n):
    # '''Partitions the nodes into n subsets'''
    nodes_iter = iter(nodes)
    while True:
        partition = tuple(itertools.islice(nodes_iter,n))
        if not partition:
            return
        yield partition


def btwn_pool(G_tuple):
    return nx.betweenness_centrality_source(*G_tuple)


def between_parallel(G, processes=None):
    p = Pool(processes=processes)
    part_generator = 4 * len(p._pool)
    node_partitions = list(partitions(G.nodes(), int(len(G) / part_generator)))
    num_partitions = len(node_partitions)

    bet_map = p.map(btwn_pool,
                    zip([G] * num_partitions,
                        [True] * num_partitions,
                        [None] * num_partitions,
                        node_partitions))

    bt_c = bet_map[0]
    for bt in bet_map[1:]:
        for n in bt:
            bt_c[n] += bt[n]
    return bt_c


bt = between_parallel(g)
top = 10

max_nodes = sorted(bt.iteritems(), key=lambda v: -v[1])[:top]
bt_values = [5] * len(g.nodes())
bt_colors = [0] * len(g.nodes())
for max_key, max_val in max_nodes:
    bt_values[max_key] = 150
    bt_colors[max_key] = 2

plt.axis("off")
nx.draw_networkx(g, pos=spring_pos, cmap=plt.get_cmap("rainbow"), node_color=bt_colors, node_size=bt_values,
                 with_labels=False)

plt.show()
```

The output it gives:
[image]

Now, let's look at the vertices with the top 10 highest betweenness centrality measures in the network.
As you can see, vertices that primarily either sit at the center of a hub or acts a bridge between two hubs have higher betweenness centrality. The bridge vertices have high betweenness because all paths connecting the hubs pass through them, and the hub center vertices have high betweenness because all intra-hub paths pass through them.